# Unknown public key when installing dependency for package in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, manjaro, pgp

I'm running Manjaro Linux and trying to install Discord app. Since Discord doesn't have an official build for Arch-based systems, I've tried to use yaourt and the install gives me this error:

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
llvm-6.0.0.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 0FC3042E345AD05D)
libcxx-6.0.0.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 0FC3042E345AD05D)
libcxxabi-6.0.0.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 0FC3042E345AD05D)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build libc++.
==> Restart building libc++ ? [y/N]
```

So even if I type "Y" to restart the build, it doesn't work because it stops at the same error again.

Is there a way to get those three public keys and manually point to them? Or another way to install the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing Discord, during the install the system will try to validate the PGP signatures for `libc++`. The signatures should be added by the user, as seen on the package instructions in the AUR ([here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libc%2B%2Babi/)).

During the install the system will ask if you want to edit the PKGBUILD, and you should input "yes". Search for the keys there, on the `validpgpkeys` array.

Copy those two keys and run in a separate window the command:

```
gpg --recv-keys <KEY_A> <KEY_B>
```

Replace `KEY_A` and `KEY_B` with the signatures found on the PKGBUILD file.

After importing those keys you should see something like this:

```
gpg: key 0FC3042E345AD05D: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 0FC3042E345AD05D: public key "Hans Wennborg <hans@chromium.org>" imported
gpg: key 8F0871F202119294: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 8F0871F202119294: public key "Tom Stellard <tom@stellard.net>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:               imported: 2
```

And then you can proceed with the `libc++` installation.